# Editing base.list during Debian upgrade

Tags: linux, debian

I'm following the installation instructions here (https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) to upgrade to Buster but I've noticed that the sources.list.d/base.list file contains the line 
`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main`
but the the instructions only mention editing the sources.list file. So base.list should be kept the same? Other tutorials on this are unclear and contradictory so I've decided to only follow the instructions on the Debian site. When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get a long list of packages that have been held back.

Comment: Editing `sources.list` is enough. Use `apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade the rest old packages.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I tried the first one. It installed most of them but some are being held back. I'd like to avoid using dist-upgrade because of this post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Comment: You should remove the `base.list` file under  `/etc/apt/sources.list/d` then run `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`.